# Active macro when a formula changes a cell to True

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am looking for some code to activate another macro when the cell changes to "True" (Cell Q1). The cell has a formula behind it: =IF(COUNTIF($T$2:$T$1618,"Implemented-N"),"No","Yes")
This formula reads a range of cells, which have a formula behind them (Column T). Column T matches and puts together the data in 2 other cells along the same row: =D2&"-"&N2
When a cell in Column T turns to "Implemented-N" it returns the value of "No" to Cell Q1.
When cell Q1 changes to "No" I would like my macro that calls up an email to be activated. 
I have the code for the email but can't get it to activate when cell Q1 changes to "No".
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You will need to place the check and the call in a Worksheet_Calculate Event.  Or bypass the formula and use a Worksheet_change event that searches the column for the desired criteria every time the data in that range changes.

Answer (score 2):

As Scott mentioned in the comments something like the following would do the trick:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Range("Q1").Value = "No" Then Call YourMacro 
'if the value of Q1 changes to No then call your macro/code
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant. I am a bit of an amateur. I had tried a few things without any luck. This works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MichaelHarmer, please could you accept my response as an answer if it has helped you? Thank you. :)